# Perl: Is it possible to DBI bind_param() as part of selectrow_arrayref()?

Tags: perl, dbi

I'd like to bind param types during the selectrow/selectall function calls.

Is it possible to change something like:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bind_param(1, undef, {pg_type => DBD::Pg::PG_BYTEA});
$sth->execute($byteavalue);
```

To a selectrow statement:

```
$dbh->selectrow_arrayref( $sql, undef, $byteavalue );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first param of `selectrow_*` can be a statement handle, so you could use:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql)
and $sth->bind_param(1, undef, { pg_type => DBD::Pg::PG_BYTEA })
and $dbh->selectrow_arrayref($sth, undef, $byteavalue);
```

Otherwise, you'll have to create your own version of `selectrow_arrayref`. The existing version is:

```
sub selectrow_arrayref {
    my ($dbh, $stmt, $attr, @bind) = @_;
    my $sth = ((ref $stmt) ? $stmt : $dbh->prepare($stmt, $attr))
        or return;
    $sth->execute(@bind)
        or return;
    my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref()
        and $sth->finish;
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: A little better, but I guess you would need to create the statement handle anyhow.

Comment: No, it you wrote your own version of `selectrow_arrayref`, you could pass the information needed for binding in a new field of the `$attr` hash. (e.g. `bind_params => [ [ 1, undef, { pg_type => DBD::Pg::PG_BYTEA } ] ]`) But it's probably clearer if you don't.